# Spyder(3.3.1) not launching in Anaconda Navigator 1.9.2

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIS2f.png)

I've Anaconda navigator setup to "Applications on 'base (root)' channels".

Spyder used to launch fine until this afternoon, something happened, and it is not launching at all. Please help!, Thank you!

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Unfortunately, the image you posted is insufficient to help you. Please open an Anaconda Prompt, run there `spyder` and post the error messages you get there as a new image in your question.

Comment: There is no error message, it is just that, the spyder window doesn't open up